# ApplicationInsights, ApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService, Set EnableAdaptiveSampling in config

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

In a "worker" application (.net core 3.1) I have configured an ApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService by:

```
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(options =>
                     {
                         options.DeveloperMode = false;
                         options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
                     });
```

In the appsettings.json the InstrumentationKey is defined as:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"   
    },
```

I want to move the "EnableAdaptiveSampling" setting from the code to json file.
When I try to add it to the ApplicationInsights section like
"EnableAdaptiveSampling": false, it doesn't seem to pick it up.

What is the correct way to set this in a config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the configuration by code and set it. In .net core, there is no automatic pickup of predefined setting for adaptive sampling like InstrumentationKey. For example:

appsettings.json:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": "false"
    },
```

Code:

```
// instrumentation key is read automatically from appsettings.json
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(options =>
                     {
                         options.DeveloperMode = false;
                         options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("ApplicationInsights:EnableAdaptiveSampling");
                     });
```

Comment: @Bart if this solves your problem, would you mind to "accept" the answer.